# Is it possible to create a thrust's function predicate for structs using a given parameter?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I want to use copy_if from CUDA's Thrust to compact a array of structs.
My struct has a id and a score. I want to copy only the structs that satisfy a minimum score. The threshold is set by the user.

```
struct is_bigger_than_threshold
{
    __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(const register x)
    {
        return (x.score > threshold);
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, and there are plenty of worked examples of thrust functors that take an initialization parameter if you look around on the thrust tag.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736801/making-the-number-of-key-occurances-equal-using-cuda-thrust/35737950#35737950) demonstrates a functor (`copy_func`) which takes two initialization parameters.  And there are other examples also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  The functor needs to accept the struct as its operator parameter, and it needs to include storage for the desired threshold.  This threshold can be passed as a parameter when the functor is used.  Here is a fully worked example:

```
$ cat t688.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <iostream>

struct my_score {

  int id;
  int score;
};

const int dsize = 10;

struct copy_func {

  int threshold;
  copy_func(int thr) : threshold(thr) {};
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(const my_score &x){
    return (x.score > threshold);
    }
};

int main(){

  thrust::host_vector<my_score> h_data(dsize);
  thrust::device_vector<my_score> d_result(dsize);
  int my_threshold = 50;
  for (int i = 0; i < dsize; i++){
    h_data[i].id = i;
    h_data[i].score = i * 10;}

  thrust::device_vector<my_score> d_data = h_data;

  int rsize = thrust::copy_if(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), d_result.begin(), copy_func(my_threshold)) - d_result.begin();

  std::cout << "There were " << rsize << " entries with a score greater than " << my_threshold << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t688 t688.cu
$ ./t688
There were 4 entries with a score greater than 50
$
```